# Can't archive project with Swift Package that contains a binary target (xcframework)

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager, xcframework

My project contains a Swift Package that contains a binary target. Generally, the project compiles and works properly, but the problem occurs when I try to archive the project, where I get a complier error saying `No such module 'MyFramework'`.
The Swift Package looks like this:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v13)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        // Product dependencies...
    ],
    targets: [
        .binaryTarget(name: "MyFramework", path: "MyFramework.xcframework"),
        .target(
             name: "MyPackage",
            dependencies: [
                "MyFramework"
                ...
            ],
            resources: [.process("Resources")]
         ),
        .testTarget(
            name: "MyPackageTests",
            dependencies: ["MyPackage"])
    ]
)
```

I've tried following many solutions, among them a [proposal from the Apple Developer forums](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662247) where I added the framework to the `products` as another library and then added the framework on the app (project / client) side, which made it archive successfully, but when I tried upload the archive to the App Store I got an error saying `Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21`.
Right now, I am trying to follow other solutions mainly on the Swift Forums but none of them seem to work for me or be clear enough.
From what I've seen, this is a [Swift Bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-13803) but I am wondering if there is any workaround that is sufficient for now.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

After too many hours we managed to find a (pretty ugly) workaround that archives properly.
Basically, we need to the framework as a library to the product, like so:

```
let package = Package(
    name: "MyPackage",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(name: "MyPackage", targets: ["MyPackage"]),
        .library(name: "MyFramework", targets: ["MyFramework"]),
    ], 
    ...
    targets: [
        ...
        .binaryTarget(name: "MyFramework", path: "MyFramework.xcframework") 
    ]
)
```

Then link the frameworks on the project in **Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content**.
This in for itself though isn't enough, as the project will archive but will throw the error `Found an unexpected Mach-O header code: 0x72613c21` like I mentioned in the original question. In order to resolve this issue, we needed to add the following script to the **Archive**'s *Post-actions* in the project's scheme:

```
LOGFILE="${ARCHIVE_PATH}/static-frameworks.log"
echo "Removing static frameworks from ${WRAPPER_NAME} archive" > $LOGFILE
find "${ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH}/Applications/${WRAPPER_NAME}" -name '*.framework' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' fm; do
    name=$(basename "${fm}" .framework)
    target="${fm}/${name}"
    echo "Checking: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    if file "${target}" | grep -q "current ar archive"; then
        rm -rf "${fm}"
        echo "Removed static framework: ${fm}" >> $LOGFILE
    fi
done
```

Now the project archives successfully an can be uploaded to the App Store. Still obviously not an ideal solution, looking forward to hearing from Apple or for other possible solutions.

Comment: Note - this issue is fixed in Xcode 12.5 and this "dirty" solution is no longer required.

Answer (score 0):

Update to Xcode 12.5 for a fix.

Much more detail and discussion [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/6472).